# getting statestore data from called function in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka Streams' Processor API, can I pass processor context from `init()` as follows to other function and get the context back with state store in `process()`?

```java
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;

    String resourceName = "config.properties"; 
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
        props.load(resourceStream);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dataSplitter.timerMessageSource(props, context);//can I pass context like this?

    this.context.schedule(1000);

    // retrieve the key-value store named "patient"
    kvStore = (KeyValueStore<String, PatientDataSummary>) this.context.getStateStore("patient"); 
    //want to get the value of statestore filled by the called function timerMessageSource(), as the data to be put in statestore is getting generated in timerMessageSource()
    //is there any way I can get that by using context or so    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `ProcessorContext` is somewhat limited and you cannot call each method is provides at arbitrary times. Thus, it depend how you use it -- in general, you can pass it around as you wish (it will always be the same object throughout the live time of the processor).

If I understand your question correctly, you register a punctuation and use your `dataSplitter` within the punctuation callback and want to modify the store. That is absolutely possible -- you can either put the store into a class member similar to what you do with the context or use the context object to get the store within the punctuate callback.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. Wanted to understand why we chose punctuate() instead of init() or process(). By that I meant, can't we get back the state store value in init() or process() itself ?

Comment: You can get the state store within init(), process(), or punctuate(). I thought you want to use punctuate as you register a punctuation via `context.schedule()`...